# Pandas concat: why is the `DataFrame` with duplicated index not working with concat()?

Tags: python, pandas

Code example:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3],}, index=[1,2,2])
b = pd.DataFrame({"b": [1,4,5],}, index=[1,4,5])
pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
```

It raises error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 2), indices imply (5, 2)`

What I expected as a result:

[image]

Why does it not return like this? `concat`'s default joining is `outer` so I think my thought is reasonable enough... Am I missing something?

Comment: try `pd.merge(a,b,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer')`

Comment: I know the solution. I'd like to know WHY IT DOES NOT WORK

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Why? I don't really know for sure, but I think it has to do with just the design of the package.

An index in pandas "is like an address, that’s how any data point across the dataframe or series **can be accessed**. Rows and columns both have indexes, rows indices are called as index and for columns its general column names." [source](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-index-explained-b131beaf6f7b)

Now you are doing it where axis = 1, aka along the vertical axis. That means that we have an address which points to two different values. Hence we can still "access" these values by doing `a[a.index == 2]`. Do note however the index in a mathematical sense is now not a proper function because one value maps to two different values [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection). *I am guessing* the implementation was designed so that indices would be injective, surjective, or bijective in order to make it easier to design.

Thus, when attempting to concatenate, pandas wants to match all the indices together where possible and fill in nans where not possible. However, as the error says, it thinks the shape based off the indices is (5, 2) because of this address sharing two different values. So why doesn't it work? Because I believe pandas checks the shape it should be before hand, and then does the concatenation. In order to check the shape before hand it looks at the indices and therefore it breaks when it checks.

Do note too that this would not work with identical column names as well:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], 'b': [9,8,7]}, index=[1,2,2])
b = pd.DataFrame({"b": [1,4,5], 'bx': [1,4,3]}, index=[1,4,5]).rename(columns={'bx': 'b'})

pd.concat([a,b]) # axis=0 is the default

ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

Therefore `pd.concat` needs unique indices along whichever axis it is operating upon. You can't have two identical column names when you normally concatenate row wise, and likewise you can't be able to do it column wise.

Interestingly, for your original example, `pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True, axis=1)` also raises the same error, leading me to more strongly suspect that pandas is checking the shape before the concatenation.